# Duplicate resources on “ionic cordova build android” command. Firebase plugin

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm building a fresh new application for android with the following plugins and commands. Cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-fcm, ionic cordova build android.
This is the error displayed:

```
Parsing json file: /home/faichi/palav-ui/platforms/android/google-services.json
        :generateDebugResources
        :mergeDebugResources
        [string/google_app_id] /home/faichi/palav-ui/platforms/android/res/values/strings.xml   [string/google_app_id]
        /home/faichi/palav-ui/platforms/android/build/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values.xml: Error:
    Duplicate resources
    :mergeDebugResources FAILED

    BUILD FAILED

    Total time: 1.683 secs

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'.
    > [string/google_app_id] /home/faichi/palav-ui/platforms/android/res/values/strings.xml [string/google_app_id]
    /home/faichi/palav-ui/platforms/android/build/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values.xml: Error:
    Duplicate resources

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
    Error: /home/faichi/palav-ui/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'.
    > [string/google_app_id] /home/faichi/palav-ui/platforms/android/res/values/strings.xml [string/google_app_id]
    /home/faichi/palav-ui/platforms/android/build/generated/res/google-services/debug/values/values.xml: Error:
    Duplicate resources
```

I've tried to delete the duplicate values on android\res\values\strings.xml but on each build its coming back and display the same error.

Is this is currect way to build a cordova based application with fire bash push notification service ?

Comment: Hi Sonu did you get any solutions for this issue.